# logic behind providing the $scope object as the argument to watchers within $digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I'm not too clear why is the $scope object provided as an argument to both the watcher as well as the listener function. 
I found t[his bit of code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/katncandix/27df3e23bf54452d6b72), it's the piece that iterates over the watchers array within $digest:

```
    this.$$watchers.forEach(function(watcher) {
    var newValue = watcher.watchFn(self);
    var oldValue = watcher.last;

    if (watcher.deep && newValue === oldValue) {
      deppCompare(newValue, oldValue);
    } else {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) dirty = true;
    }

    watcher.listenerFn(newValue, oldValue, self);
    watcher.last = newValue;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the scenes, when you declare it a watch function in a certain scope, angular parse the expression given in a function:

```
//The code of a random watcher
$scope.$watch('myVariable', listenerFunction);

//Behind the scenes
$scope.$watch(function(scope){
  return scope.myVariable;
}, listenerFunction);
```

When you register a watcher, the expected behaviour it's that "in **THIS SCOPE**, i need watch the changes for the variable attached in **THIS SCOPE**", therefore, behind the scenes the first argument of the `$watch()` parsed by angular for return the expected variable should be a variable in the scope where a watch function was attached.